# join table to Gap and Islands SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, join, teradata, gaps-and-islands

I have data stored on the DB as gaps and islands and I need to join it with another table.
the gaps and islands table like the below:

```
|Subs_ID|ORIGINAL_STATUS|NEW_STATUS|CHANGE_DATE|
|-------+---------------+----------+-----------|
|123456 |1              |2         |12/2/2017  |
|123456 |2              |3         |12/8/2019  |
|123456 |3              |4         |12/18/2019 |
|123456 |4              |8         |12/28/2019 |
|123456 |8              |9         |10/4/2020  |
```

the second table only includes the Subs_ID and sequenced Connect_date

```
|Subs_ID|CONNECT_DATE|
|-------+------------|
|123456 |12/1/2017   |
|123456 |12/3/2017   |
|123456 |11/4/2018   |
|123456 |10/5/2019   |
|123456 |12/30/2019  |
|123456 |10/4/2020   |
|123456 |5/21/2021   |
```

I need to join the current `STATUS` from the first table to the second one using the `subs_id` and the `dates`. and the result will be the below where if the `Connect_date` less than the `Change_Date` will take the first `ORIGINAL_STATUS` and vs if the `Connect_date` more than the `Change_Date` will take the `last NEW_STATUS`

```
|Subs_ID|CONNECT_DATE|Status|
|-------+------------+------|
|123456 |12/1/2017   |1     |
|123456 |12/3/2017   |2     |
|123456 |11/4/2018   |2     |
|123456 |10/5/2019   |2     |
|123456 |12/30/2019  |8     |
|123456 |10/4/2020   |8     |
|123456 |5/21/2021   |9     |
```

Comment: How do you get the CONNECT_DATE of first two rows?

Comment: yes , where CONNECT_DATE data come from in your output?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my fault while writing the question, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this query helps you. Code breakdown and explanation given below

```
select a.*,B.ORIGINAL_STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (select *,LAG(CHANGE_DATE) OVER(ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE) as previous_date_value
from mytable)b
on a.Subs_ID =b.Subs_ID and a.CONNECT_DATE >b.previous_date_value and a.CONNECT_DATE<= b.CHANGE_DATE

UNION

select * from (
select a.*,CASE WHEN A.CONNECT_dATE<B.CHANGE_DATE THEN b.ORIGINAL_STATUS ELSE NULL END AS STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE from
(
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE,row_number() over(partition by Subs_ID order by CHANGE_DATE)rn
from mytable
)mytable_less
where rn=1)b
on a.Subs_ID=b.Subs_ID)less_than_available_date
where status is not null

UNION

select * from (
select a.*,CASE WHEN A.CONNECT_dATE>B.CHANGE_DATE THEN b.NEW_STATUS ELSE NULL END AS STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE from
(
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE,row_number() over(partition by Subs_ID order by CHANGE_DATE desc)rn
from mytable
)mytable_less
where rn=1)b
on a.Subs_ID=b.Subs_ID)greater_than_available_date
where status is not null
```

Explanation: First block of code with return the status of the connect date if the connect date is present with in the range of available change dates. I am using lag function to fetch previous change date value and comparing with connect date.

```
select a.*,B.ORIGINAL_STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (select *,LAG(CHANGE_DATE) OVER(ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE) as previous_date_value
from mytable)b
on a.Subs_ID =b.Subs_ID and a.CONNECT_DATE >b.previous_date_value and a.CONNECT_DATE<= b.CHANGE_DATE
```

This gives us the following result set

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| Subs_ID | CONNECT_DATE | ORIGINAL_STATUS |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|  123456 | 2017-12-03   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2018-11-04   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2019-10-05   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2019-12-30   |               8 |
|  123456 | 2020-10-04   |               8 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Now we want to find the status of 12/1/2017 which is lesser than the available change date. table 2 is joined with table 1 which has the row of minimum change date and ORIGINAL_STATUS is taken if the connect date is lesser than change date..

```
select * from (
select a.*,CASE WHEN A.CONNECT_dATE<B.CHANGE_DATE THEN b.ORIGINAL_STATUS ELSE NULL END AS STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE from
(
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE,row_number() over(partition by Subs_ID order by CHANGE_DATE)rn
from mytable
)mytable_less
where rn=1)b
on a.Subs_ID=b.Subs_ID)less_than_available_date
where status is not null

+---------+--------------+--------+
| Subs_ID | CONNECT_DATE | STATUS |
+---------+--------------+--------+
|  123456 | 2017-12-01   |      1 |
+---------+--------------+--------+
```

Left over is the records with connect date greater than available change date. This is achieved by below code and table 2 is joined with table 1 having the row of max change date and new status is taken if the connect date is greater than change date.

```
select * from (
select a.*,CASE WHEN A.CONNECT_dATE>B.CHANGE_DATE THEN b.NEW_STATUS ELSE NULL 
END AS STATUS
from mytable2 a
join (
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE from
(
select Subs_ID,ORIGINAL_STATUS,NEW_STATUS,CHANGE_DATE,row_number() 
over(partition by Subs_ID order by CHANGE_DATE desc)rn
from mytable
)mytable_less
where rn=1)b
on a.Subs_ID=b.Subs_ID)greater_than_available_date
where status is not null

    +---------+--------------+--------+
    | Subs_ID | CONNECT_DATE | STATUS |
    +---------+--------------+--------+
    |  123456 | 2021-05-21   |      9 |
    +---------+--------------+--------+
```

Finally after applying union we get the required resultset

```
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
| Subs_ID | CONNECT_DATE | ORIGINAL_STATUS |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
|  123456 | 2017-12-01   |               1 |
|  123456 | 2017-12-03   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2018-11-04   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2019-10-05   |               2 |
|  123456 | 2019-12-30   |               8 |
|  123456 | 2020-10-04   |               8 |
|  123456 | 2021-05-21   |               9 |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: @PrakaaH M thanks a lot for your kind help, I'll try the given code and preview its performance as i worked with a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this kind of problem avoiding a non-equi-join:

```
SELECT
   Subs_ID
  ,dt AS CONNECT_DATE
 -- fill the NULLs
 -- if the Connect_date more than the Change_Date will take the last NEW_STATUS  
  ,Coalesce(Lag(NEW_STATUS IGNORE NULLS)
            Over (PARTITION BY Subs_ID
                  ORDER BY dt)
 -- if the Connect_date less than the Change_Date will take the first ORIGINAL_STATUS 
           ,Lead(ORIGINAL_STATUS IGNORE NULLS)
            Over (PARTITION BY Subs_ID
                  ORDER BY dt)
           )
FROM 
 ( -- combine both tables
   SELECT
      1 AS x -- flag indicating the source tables
     ,Subs_ID
     ,ORIGINAL_STATUS
     ,NEW_STATUS
     ,CHANGE_DATE AS dt
   FROM t1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      2 AS x
     ,Subs_ID
     ,NULL -- to get the same number of columns
     ,NULL -- to get the same number of columns
     ,CONNECT_DATE 
   FROM t2
 ) AS t
QUALIFY x = 2 -- return only rows from t2
ORDER BY CONNECT_DATE
;
```

To see how it works comment the QUALIFY.

If your data allows removing IGNORE NULLS in the LEAD it will be more efficient (only one STAT step instead of two).

Comment: @dnoath the query takes a long time as the both tables have millions or billions of rows, and the second table has other columns that I need to use them but it didn't include in the sample to simplify the question

Comment: What's the number of rows per table and the avg/max per `Subs_ID`?

Comment: the first table has 845 million rows with AVG subs 315 million rows, and the second table has billions or rows and 13 million rows as AVG subs

Comment: 315 million rows per Subs_ID? Or 315 million Subs_IDs, i.e. a single digit rows per value?

Comment: I mean 315 million distinct Subs_IDs

Comment: Well, you can go for a non-equi-join based on BETWEEN, but you still need to create **6** rows with date ranges from your **5** example rows in table 1 before the join. If this is a common query you should change your data model to a Slowly Changing Dimension ,`valid_from/valid_to`.